# Starting localhost shows Internet Explorer can not display web page

Tags: iis, windows-7, localhost

When I type http://localhost, I get the message as Internet explorer can not display web page. It is happening in Win 7 Professional. I have turned on all the windows features related to IIS. IIS service is also in running mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a problem with how your browser connects to the IIS. By default IE will try IPv6 before it will fallback on IPv4 so if you add

::1    localhost

into your hosts file in %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\ you'll be fine.

**Edit 1:**
Have you tried the standard loopback http://127.0.0.1? Do you get the same result then? If that doesnt work then you at least ruled out the DNS problem.

Comment: Still the same issue, http://localhost, does not show default web page. Any of the web application is not working